# Angular cookies not created in SSL unix environment

Tags: angularjs, unix, ssl, cookies, weblogic12c

I tried to create cookies using ngCookies in Angularjs which worked fine in my windows environment and when I deployed my code in unix environment, cookie is not created in unix environment. Do I need to do anything specific to make cookie create in unix environment ? I use the weblogic 12c server. Everything works fine in weblogic-windows environment and the unix one is not creating the cookies.

Controller

```
mdmApp.controller('listController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope,    $cookies) {
$cookies.put('loggedInUser', $rootScope.loggedInUser);
     }
```

Comment: It exactly happens the same for localstorage - ngStorage. Works in windows weblogic environment and fails to create in unix weblogic environment. I dont find any difference other than this.